# R - How to find the difference between every consecutive row for each column

Tags: r

```
Date    FXDL.AED.USD    FXDL.ALL.USD    FXDL.AMD.USD    FXDL.ANG.USD  
03/01/2005  3.6726  92.1    484 1.779999971  
04/01/2005  3.6726  92.1    487 1.779999971  
05/01/2005  3.6725  94.5    490.5   1.779999971 
06/01/2005  3.6726  95.1    490.5   1.779999971 
07/01/2005  3.6725  95.3    493.5   1.779999971 
08/01/2005  NA  NA  NA  NA  
09/01/2005  NA  NA  NA  NA  
10/01/2005  3.6726  96.9    497.5   1.779999971  
11/01/2005  3.6725  97.2    502.5   1.779999971
```

I have a number of columns in a dataframe, above is a small portion of it, I want to find the difference between every consecutive row for each column. For example, the values for each column in rows 3 - 2, rows 4 - 3, rows 5 - 4 etc.

I have used the following code:

```
x_diff <- x[-1,] - x[-nrow(x),]
```

but this comes up with an error, I assume that is because there are NA terms in some fields but I wish to also include these NA terms in the summation so it can simply return NA.

EDIT:

```
structure(list(Weekday = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Date = structure(c(1104710400, 
1104796800, 1104883200, 1104969600, 1105056000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), FXDL.AED.USD = c("3.6726000000000001", 
"3.6726000000000001", "3.6724999999999999", "3.6726000000000001", 
"3.6724999999999999"), FXDL.ALL.USD = c("92.1", "92.1", "94.5", 
"95.1", "95.3"), FXDL.AMD.USD = c("484", "487", "490.5", "490.5", 
"493.5")), .Names = c("Weekday", "Date", "FXDL.AED.USD", "FXDL.ALL.USD", 
"FXDL.AMD.USD"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: `sapply(x[ , sapply(x, is.numeric)], diff)`. The preceding code will apply the `diff` function (difference between two values) to each numeric column in data frame `x`.

Comment: Thanks! However this seems to only do it for the first column.

Comment: @isuckatcoding ; eipi10's code should work, so can you add a small example of your data to your question: you can do this by adding the results of `dput(x[1:5, 1:5])` to your question. thanks. (ps i think you can avoid the `sapply` ineipi's code by explicitly converting to a matrix ... `diff(as.matrix(x[, sapply(x, is.numeric)]))` )

Comment: hi @user20650 I've edited my question with the dput function. I've tried converting it to a matrix but yet it again it only does it for one column...

Comment: thanks. okay, have a look at `str(x)` and you will see that the values that look like numbers are actually character (and why `sapply(x, is.numeric)` only finds one numeric column). You can convert these to numeric via `as.numeric` but really it would be better to try and find where this happens earlier in your code and try to fix it there

Comment: it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(c(NA, diff(as.numeric(.)))), 3:5)
```